# SCP files matching pattern using Perl

Tags: perl, scp

Is there a way to scp multiple files matching a wildcard pattern using Perl?

say server A has curr directory contains .pdf and .txt files and I want to move just the .pdf files to server B under /home/userid
I used Net::SCP, but I see there is no bulk copy as in normal scp command eg. scp *.pdf userid@serverB

```
>cat test.pl
use Net::SCP;
$scp = Net::SCP->new( "serverB", "userid" );
$scp->put("test.pdf") or die $scp->{errstr};
```

I want to change to $scp->put("*.pdf") or die $scp->{errstr}; If I change to *.pdf perl throws error

> *.pdf: No such file or directory

I already created passwordless login. Is there a way to do bulk copy of matching pattern files ?

Answer (score 2):

Using [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::OpenSSH):

```
use Net::OpenSSH;
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new('serverB', user => 'userid');
$ssh->scp_put({glob => 1}, '*.pdf', '.') or die $ssh->error;
```

Or, if you are running that script in Windows, [Net::SSH::Any](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Any) provides an  identical interface:

```
use Net::SSH::Any;
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Any->new('serverB', user => 'userid');
$ssh->scp_put({glob => 1}, '*.pdf', '.') or die $ssh->error;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `*` character is a wildcard that is expanded by your shell (and different shells may have different expansion rules), so SSH (or SCP) knows nothing about it.

Also, SSH does not have "integrated" support for listing files in directories.
If you want to list the files, you'll have to either go the "ugly way", by doing a remote `ls *.pdf` (by using [Net::SSH::Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~schwigon/Net-SSH-Perl-2.01/lib/Net/SSH/Perl.pm)) , or switch to something different like [Net::SFTP](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Net-SFTP-0.08/lib/Net/SFTP.pm), which supports an `opendir` function.